# IFC conversionMethods "modern" and "v3" don't seem to be working

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-navisworks

Good Day,

I'm trying to convert an IFC file using the "Revit engine".
I've tried conversionMethods "modern" and "v3".
`https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/`
SVF2 Output > Formats > advanced

But the "Navisworks engine" is always used.

Here is the Request Header:

```
Content-Type: application/json
x-ads-derivative-format: fallback
x-ads-force: true
Authorization: Bearer ...
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 60ace5f6-a41c-4314-b3de-e2057f4f8795
Host: developer.api.autodesk.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 521
Cookie: PF=zlUuSLBAdPBYRrnJUXxwq1
```

Here is the Request Body:

```
{
    "input": {
        "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bmVhbmV4LXN0YWdpbmcxLTE2MTk2MTgyOTM4MjMvMTY1NTIxOTY2OTY5MS1BQzIwLUZaSy1IYXVzLmlmYw"
    },
    "output": {
        "destination": {
            "region": "us"
        },
        "formats": [
            {
                "type": "svf2",
                "views": [
                    "3d"
                ],
                "advanced": {
                    "conversionMethod": "v3"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The Response:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bmVhbmV4LXN0YWdpbmcxLTE2MTk2MTgyOTM4MjMvMTY1NTIxOTY2OTY5MS1BQzIwLUZaSy1IYXVzLmlmYw",
    "acceptedJobs": {
        "output": {
            "destination": {
                "region": "us"
            },
            "formats": [
                {
                    "type": "svf2",
                    "views": [
                        "3d"
                    ],
                    "advanced": {
                        "conversionMethod": "v3"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a snippet from the Manifest:

```
"name": "........ifc",
"progress": "complete",
"outputType": "svf2",
"properties": {
    "Document Information": {
        "Navisworks File Creator": "LcNwcLoaderPlugin:lcldifc",
        "IFC Application Name": "ARCHICAD-64",
        "IFC Application Version": "20.0.0",
        "IFC Organization": "GRAPHISOFT",
        "IFC Schema": "IFC4",
        "IFC Loader": "3"
    }
},
"status": "success"
```

Any ideas?

TIA

Wolfgang

Comment: look you missed passing x-ads-force: true to the request header

Comment: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#headers

Comment: I used `x-ads-force: true`:  
```
POST https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job
200
1562 ms
Network
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
x-ads-derivative-format: fallback
x-ads-force: true
Authorization:
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot tell if your request is correct. Could you put it inside your question above?

Comment: BTW, the file is stored in an OSS bucket.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproducible this issue on my side, so another thing to check is to open your viewer app in the [incontgo mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en-GB&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop), and append this query string to your app URL `?disableIndexedDb=true` to clear caches. e.g. `http://localhost/?disableIndexedDb=true`

Comment: I can send you a Postman collection to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi @WoWen, could you send a reproducible case to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works as designed, but the documentation is not clear on this issue.

The documentation says that the Revit IFC Loader is used for modern and V3:
[image: POST translation IFC options]

Also, this blog post mentions that Revit will be used instead of Navisworks:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-ifc-pipeline-call-change

So you would expect that the external IDs in the properties to be Revit element IDs or uniqueIDs when using modern or V3.

But all IFC conversion methods are running on the Cloud version of Navisworks on Forge env.
Both modern and v3 IFC conversion methods or loaders are based on the Revit technics integrated with Navisworks, so they are called Revit-based IFC loaders.
You can see a similar thing on Navisworks Desktop.
[image: Navisworks IFC reader options]

You can check which conversion method was used in the Manifest (> `"IFC Loader": "3"`).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed passing `x-ads-force: true` to the request header. Could you call the API like this way?

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'x-ads-force: true' \
--data-raw '{
    "input": {
        "urn": ""
    },
    "output": {
        "formats": [
            {
                "type": "svf2",
                "views": [
                    "3d"
                ],
                "advanced": {
                    "conversionMethod": "v3"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```